# Left shift number with string

Tags: javascript

```
10000<<"5daz"
```

I am applying left shift between number and string, the result is 10000, how is it interpreted in JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>JavaScript Variables</h1>
        <p>In this example, x, y, and z are variables</p>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var x = 5;
            var y = 6;
            var z = x + y;
            var bvalue=true;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 10000<<"5daz";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's interpreted as `10000 << NaN`, so it doesn't shift at all

Comment: If you want to know why JavaScript behaves the way it does, look at the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator (and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint32) . `10000<<"5daz"` is the same as `10000<<0`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript generally attempts to resolve the types of the arguments to its operators so that they "make sense".  In this case it is casting a `String` to a `Uint32` so that it can perform the left shift.  When casting a `String` to a `Uint32`, it first casts it to a `Number`.  [If the number is `NaN`, then the UInt32 is 0 by the specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32)

`10000<<"5daz"` is the same as `10000<<0` which is `10000`

For more reading, [here in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator).

In other operations, `NaN` is treated differently which may be why this surprised you for the `<<` operator.  For instance, addition treats the arguments as `Number`s, instead of `Uint32`.  For this reason `10000 + "5daz" = NaN` whereas `10000 << "5daz" = 10000`